# method return types

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure out the best way to test if a method returns correctly, ie; did the method get the information I wanted.

It's the types that are making this difficult. Is there a way that I can sometimes return bool and sometimes return something else?

In PHP I would create my function like this

```
function myFunc(){
    //Do Stuff
    if(/*whatever*/) return (string) "abcdefg";
    return false; //otherwise it will just return false
}
```

Then call it like this to test if it worked or not

```
if(!$var=myFunc()) die("It Didn't Work");
echo $var;
```

But with C#, my function has to return a specified type, not a string or bool false if it didn't work out.

If in C# I have a method that returns IntPtr I could have it return `(IntPtr) 0` instead of false, but this is messy and there's probably a better way of doing it.

Any Ideas? What's the standard and usual way of doing this in C#?

Comment: I usually just return `null` in cases where a method is expected to fail occasionally.

Comment: Please define "method didn't work out".  Do you mean there was an exception?

Comment: you could return null, if you make the return type nullable

Comment: C# is type-safe.. intended to avoid issues like this one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are typically two approaches here:

1. Use [Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)
2. Use the TryXXX approach.

The appropriate method depends on what this is doing.  If the "false" case is really something that's exceptional and not the norm, raising an exception is an appropriate way of handling it.

If, however, you're doing something like parsing user input, where its common that you'll "fail", using the TryXXX approach is a good example.  This would look like:

```
bool TryMyFunc(out string result)
{
     if (...)
     {
         result = "abcdefg";
         return true;
     }

     result = string.Empty;
     return false;
}
```

This is how [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) works in the framework, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can always return null.

```
string Foo()
{
    if (!success) return null;
    return "abcd";
}
```

You then check the call like that:

```
var tmp = Foo();
if (tmp == null) return -1;
// tmp is a string so do your work
```

The null return will only work with object, unfortunately you can't do that with an int. In that case throw an exception or use a nullable int:

```
int? Bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example I would return null from your function in C#:

```
public string myFunc(){
    //Do Stuff
    if(/*whatever*/) return "abcdefg";
    return null;
}
```

And then in your calling code:

```
string myVar = myFunc();

if(null != myVar)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

Console.WriteLine(myVar);
```

It should be noted though that any time you throw exceptions for non-exceptional circumstances (meaning, if your call to myFunc could, in reasonable usage, return null) you will take a serious performance hit. It takes a long time to generate an exception, so it's generally better to avoid them, perhaps by using a pre-requisite check before even calling myFunc.

In circumstances where you're dealing with non-nullable value types, C# has a concept called [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: -1 Sorry, but your code is messy and won't compile. For example `var` is not initialized before it's used and the comparision does not make any sense.

Comment: @ChrisWue Thanks for the catch, I've fixed the code to compile.

Answer (score 1):

If your Intention is how to return types you can use Tuple<>

```
public Tuple<string,bool> myFunc()
{
    //Do Stuff
    if(/*whatever*/) return (string) new Tuple<string,bool>("abcdefg",true);
    return new Tuple<string,bool>(null,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Exception based programming:

```
public string Blah()
{
    if (whatever)
    {
        return "abcdefg";
    }
    throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
}
```

Or you could return null or string.Empty

Comment: Depending on how frequently `whatever` could fail, this could be miserably inefficient. Using exceptions to control application flow is generally a bad idea. No downvote though because it is certainly a viable alternative, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @KileyNaro Considering how he calls it with "die" He wants an exception anyway?

Comment: Absolutely! That's why I didn't -1. It was just something I figured that I would note.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer use null.

```
public string foo()
{
    if (whatever)
    {
        return "abc"; 
    }

    return null; 
}
```

and Then:

```
 if(foo() != null) 
  {
    //do something  
  }
  else 
  {
   // *It Didn't Work*
  }
```